# How to copy a database from one django project to another

Tags: django

I have a django project with a very large database in production.  Ideally I want to copy a few tables from that environment to my dev enviroment.   How can I do that without jeopardizing the integrity of the production database?

Comment: A few tables or a few (hundred?) rows from each table? Which database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the database that you are using.

- For mysql you have [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html)
- For postgre you have [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/backup.html)
- ...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Django fixtures:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/

manage.py has two commands, "dumpdata" and "loaddata" which will dump your data to JSON so it can be imported to your dev server model by model.